# Porque no carga las imagenes en mi pagina web, con el codigo forbidden 403

Tags: javascript, html, css

He subido una pagina con adobe Muse, y las imagenes no cargan, he probado en otro hosting y si se puede, que siginifica el forbidden 403.

Agradeceré me expliquen este efecto.

Gracias y saludos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: significa que la acción o el recurso que se esta solicitando no es perimitdo o se tiene acceso denegado

Answer (score 1):

Debes configurar correctamente los permisos, parece que estás utilizando `Nginx` como `Web server` en una distribución linuxera, por ende, ejecuta el siguiente comando:

```
chmod 755 /ruta/de/tu/public_html/images/ -v
```

O mediante el programa `FTP` dale esos permisos a tu carpeta en el servidor.

Answer (score 0):

El error 403 del protocolo HTTP indica que se ha denegado el acceso a la URL que intentas acceder del servidor web. Un ejemplo de cuándo ocurre esto seria al intentar acceder a una URL del panel de administración de una web sin estar identificado como administrador de la misma. También se suele usar para impedir el acceso a directorios privados del servidor web.

En cuanto a cómo solucionarlo en tu caso ya que se supone que el administrador del servidor eres tú, prueba a ver si la respuesta de @fredyfx te sirve.